# Fixing no-param-reassign Eslint issue in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

With below code, I am getting ESlint error `Assignment to property of function parameter 'recurrence'` at many places where I `// eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign` disabled the line. I dont want to use disable. How so solve this issue without using disable as legit way? Can anyone help me with this? THanks

```
   onUpdateRecurrence = (recurrence) => {
    const todayDay = moment().format('D');
    const currentMonth = moment().format('M');
    if (recurrence.frequency === 'MONTHLY') {
      if (recurrence.days) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        delete recurrence.days;
      }
      if (recurrence.day_of_month) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        recurrence.day_of_month = recurrence.day_of_month;
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        recurrence.day_of_month = `${todayDay}${this.getDaySuffix(todayDay)}`;
      }
      if (recurrence.month) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        recurrence.month = recurrence.month;
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        recurrence.month = currentMonth;
      }
    }
    if (recurrence.frequency === 'WEEKLY') {
      if (recurrence.day_of_month) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        delete recurrence.day_of_month;
      }
      if (recurrence.month) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        delete recurrence.month;
      }
    }
    if (recurrence.frequency === 'DAILY') {
      if (recurrence.day_of_month) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        delete recurrence.day_of_month;
      }
      if (recurrence.month) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        delete recurrence.month;
      }
      if (recurrence.days) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        delete recurrence.days;
      }
    }
    return recurrence;
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign recurrence to a `const` variable in side the function and use that in side the function.

```
 onUpdateRecurrence = (recurrence) => {
    const recurrenceValue = {...recurrence};

   //Your Code
 }
```

Comment: So Now I have to replace `recurrence.frequency` with `recurrenceValue.frequency` every place where `recurrence` is used?

Comment: yes exactly. or just a simply change the parameter name to something else and set `const`variable name as `recurrence`. so now you don't have to replace everywhere.

Comment: Thanks.... Can you help me here too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023755/how-to-solve-this-assignment-to-property-of-function-parameter